# Safari: Forms not submitting, works in other browsers

Tags: php, html, forms, safari, submit

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my forms. They are all on one page, I dont know if this will be an issue.

I dont know if it's my Safari or what.

Anyways heres the HTML:

```
<!-- Table Show/Hide Change Form -->
    <form method="get" action="check.php" onsubmit="setTimeout('location.reload()');">
      <div id="arrange-form" class="modal hide fade">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h4><?php _e('Customise Table Layout'); ?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="message"></div>
                        <div class="control">
                            <div id="show-form">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" data-complete-text="<?php _e('Done'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><?php _e('Submit'); ?></button>
                    <p class="pull-left"><?php _e('You can show or hide columns here.'); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Add Account Form -->
    <form method="get" action="account-update.php" onsubmit="setTimeout('location.reload()');">
      <div id="add-form" class="modal hide fade">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h4><?php _e('Add Account'); ?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="message"></div>
                        <div class="control">
            <div id="add-account-form">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" data-complete-text="<?php _e('Done'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><?php _e('Submit'); ?></button>
                    <p class="pull-left"><?php _e('Add an Account here.'); ?></p>

                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Edit/Delete Account Form -->
    <form method="get" action="edit.php" onsubmit="setTimeout('location.reload()');">
      <div id="edit-form" class="modal hide fade">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h4><?php _e('Edit/Delete Account'); ?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="message"></div>
                        <div class="control">
            <div id="edit-account-form">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" data-complete-text="<?php _e('Done'); ?>" name="add" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><?php _e('Submit'); ?></button>
                    <p class="pull-left"><button type="button" id="delete-it" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><?php _e('Delete'); ?></button></p>

                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Delete Confirm -->
    <form method="get" action="delete.php" onsubmit="setTimeout('location.reload()');">
        <div id="delete-confirm" class="modal hide fade">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                    <h4><?php _e('Delete Account?'); ?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="message"></div>
                        <div class="control">
            <div id="delete-confirm-form">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" data-complete-text="<?php _e('Done'); ?>" name="delete" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><?php _e('Yes'); ?></button>
                    <p class="pull-left"><button type="button" id="delete-refresh" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><?php _e('No'); ?></button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

The forms work in all other browsers including IE, so I don't know what the issue could be.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Are all the forms broken on Safari? How does the form break on Safari?

Comment: It just doesn't submit but it does this onsubmit="setTimeout('location.reload()');" It reloads the page, could this be an issue?

Comment: Do you see any errors in Safari console?

Comment: No I dont see any errors, I took out that onsubmit and it works. Do you have an alternative to that? Like after submitting, to refresh the page...

Comment: Well. When you submit a page, doesn't it already refresh it?

Comment: @jsalonen thanks for trying to help! I just removed the onsubmit and all of them work. I did add the onsubmit="window.location.load();" and it worked as well. But I dont need it to refresh anymore!

Comment: Great to hear that! Happy coding! ^_^